# CakePHP Auth User Information

Tags: php, session, cakephp, variables, authentication

In my view i am trying to display the current logged in users information and have figured i can do this by using

```
echo "Welcome back " .$this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'). "
```

This displays the username and i can use the same approach to display the other fields in that database row, however some of the other fields can update at anytime but does not update on the users page until they logout and login again.

Is this correct way to do it? or can this be done a better way and somehow put some code in the beforeFilter() in AppController to continue to update the variables on each page load?

Comment: you should also use h() around it to secure the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to get the real time data instead of the session data

```
var $uses = array('User');

function beforeFilter(){
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id'); //Using the session's user id is fine because it doesn't change/update
    $user_data = $this->User->findById($id);
    $user_fname = $user_data['User']['fname'];
    $this->set('fname', $user_fname);
}

//In your view
echo 'Welcome Back '. $fname . '!';
```

Comment: this looks perfect however i get the following error - Call to a member function findById() on a non-object

Comment: I updated the answer to include the User model in the appController.

Comment: @TimJoyce, why do you prefer to get the real time data, rather than session, can you explain?

Comment: @mgPePe If your user has made changes to their user record, that doesn't reflect in session until the session is destroyed and recreated. If a user changes their first name from Frank to Al, session will still say Frank until the session is refreshed.

Comment: @TimJoyce -- however, I just noticed - if you log in, then change a value in DB, and call `$this->Auth->user()` it will be the old information. Which means it still doesn't hit the db, so there is no real advantage using it

Comment: @TimJoyce So it doesn't matter if you pull it from `Session` or from `Auth`

Answer (score 1):

If the database is updated from outside CakePHP and without calling any controller action it seems the only solution for this is making a query on every loaded page to get the current value.

For this, you should use the `beforeFilter` method on the AppController:

```
function beforeFilter(){
     $user = $this->User->field('name', array('User.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')));
     $this->Session->write('Auth.User', $user);
}
```

Otherwise, you can make use of JavaScript and AJAX to get the data from time to time.

Comment: that could also do the trick but i get - Fatal error: Call to a member function field() on a non-object in

Comment: You have to include the model you want to use at the AppController with the `$uses` variable as detailed in CakePHP documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses

Answer (score 0):

What if you just made an `afterSave()` on the User model, and in it, set `$this->Session->write('Auth.User') = $user;`

This is non-tested, but seems like it should work - then your session would always be up to date on any changes.

**Edit:**

Per your comment, if the data is being pulled from a third-party source that you don't have access to, and you need to make sure it's updated on EVERY page load, then yes, the AppController's beforeFilter() is just fine.

If, however you only need it on certain pages, or certain elements, you can call the update then, or via a requestAction of an element.

Comment: the problem i see (have not tested) is that the data is not changed through this application, the database is updated from another application and this solution i assume only updates it after a cakephp form save...

Comment: @medoix - That would have been something worth mentioning in your question.